# PageControl with multiple xib's?

Tags: ios, cocoa, uiscrollview, pagecontrol

I'm having trouble with getting Page Control set up with multiple xib's. I searched on Stack on the internet for a while now but all I've been getting is getting Page Control set up with an Array with colors or images. Is it possible to get a UIScrollView with PageControl for multiple View Controllers? I'm thinking that I should use (initwithNibName: method), but I'm not sure on how to set it up with the scrollview. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Check this very useful library out. It's an iPhone UIScrollView with horizontal paging like mobile Safari tabs [HGPageScrollView](http://100grams.github.com/HGPageScrollView/).
It works pretty great in our app.

[GitHub HGPageScrollView](https://github.com/100grams/HGPageScrollView).

[UPDATE]

Here's another example. Check this [link](http://www.wannabegeek.com/?p=168).

Comment: Thanks for answering! Do you know any other way to do this without having having the Safari Style tabs? I want to have 2 views right next to each other if possible. Thanks again.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Visit that link I've provided for a simple tutorial on Page control. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much! That was EXACTLY what I was looking for! If i could upvote your answer 1000 times, i would :p Thanks Again!